# How to Package and deploy a Swings application on other system / network

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I am pretty new to Eclipse.
While playing around with Window builder Option to develop a swings program I have struck a hurdle.
I have created a simple book management system, which I want to make it as an executable [ similar to a software installation ] and run it on other system/network [ just like a double click and go ].

Have tried to explore many options that posted on-line ( which were not specifically for Window builder or swings program ) but in vain.

Any help or directions on this front would help me in clearing out this hurdle.

Cheers...!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can export your project as an executable jar. Right-click on your project, then Export, Java, Runnable JAR file. This will create the closest thing to an executable you can easily get with Java. It can be executed with a double click.

Comment: I have tried it, But It only executes on my system. But when I am transferring the same Runnable .jar ( Fat jar :P ) on other system it failed to open even thought Java was present in there system.

Comment: What exactly does "failed" mean? Does nothing happen or do you get some kind of error message? Also have you checked if the JRE version on your other machine is >= the version your project is for?

Comment: My bad, I had some security issues because of this i was not able to run that JAR. After reducing the restrictions things starting to work as expected . Thnx for your suggestion